# Problema usando TStringList con resultados de query en C++ Builder

Tags: c++, select

C++ Builder en Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin con NexusDB.

Buenas,

Estoy haciendo el siguiente código para meter los resultados de una consulta en un TStringList:

```
ListaClientesPermitidos->Clear();

std::unique_ptr< TnxQuery >query(DataModule->EjecutarSQL(Format("SELECT ClienteId FROM UsuariosClientesPermitidos WHERE UsuarioId = CAST('%s' AS Guid)", ARRAYOFCONST((UsuarioId)))));

while (query->Eof == false)
{
    ListaClientesPermitidos->Add("'" + query->FieldByName("ClienteId")->AsString + "'");

    query->Next();
}
```

Los resultados los necesito para agregar una condición en otra consulta, hago lo siguiente:

```
condiciones = condiciones +  Sysutils::Format("AND ClienteId IN (%s)", ARRAYOFCONST((usuario->ListaClientesPermitidos->CommaText)));
```

El primer problema que me aparece es que no se puede convertir de NULLSTRING a GUID ya que el campo ClienteId es de tipo GUID, y si tengo entendido lo único que debería hacer es CAST a los valores que meta en la lista, tipo:

```
 ListaClientesPermitidos->Add("CAST('" + query->FieldByName("ClienteId")->AsString + "' AS GUID)");
```

Pero ahí es donde se me presenta el segundo problema, cuando hago esto me da el siguiente error:

```
ocurrió un error al contectarseRemObjects.SDK.Types.ServerException: An exception occurred on the server: NexusDB: : Query preparation failed: Invalid token: error at line 4 pos 53 [$3CA0/15520]
```

hice debug y me aparece que la lista lleva extra unas comillas y diagonales inversas, lo cual no sucede hasta que pongo el CAST.

Que estoy haciendo mal?, o quizás estoy atacando mal el problema?, no llevo mucho programando en C++ Builder así que desconozco si hay una forma mas fácil de hacerlo.

PD: Es la primera pregunta que hago, disculpen si me falta algo.

Gracias de antemano.